# Clear varnish of specific service php

Tags: php, varnish

we have set up the varnish on a remote server and our application is communicating with its private IP.
what I want to do is to clear the cache using PHP script.

so actually I will create a form with an input field where the cache will be clear of the provided URL.

I have tried it using curl requests like this but it gives me an error.

```
  $curlOptionList = [
    CURLOPT_URL => '10.1.8.4/' . 'index.php',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PURGE',
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS => 2000,
];
$curlHandler = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curlHandler, $curlOptionList);
curl_exec($curlHandler);
curl_close($curlHandler);
```

[image]

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: What does your VCL look like? In the end you have to explicitly return purge in the VCL to allow that kind of request.

Comment: thanks, @gonzo, your comment helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Varnish can purge from VCL, but you will have to explicitly return (purge) to do so.

See: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/purging.html#http-purging

This is the archetypical example of purging from the same machine:

```
acl purge {
        "localhost";
}

sub vcl_recv {
        # allow PURGE from localhost    
        if (req.method == "PURGE") {
                if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
                        return(synth(405,"Not allowed."));
                }
                return (purge);
        }
}
```